# Overfitting on Missing Value Imputations

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation, overfitting

When performing Missing Value imputations, should we be concerned about overfitting the data?  Why or why not?  For example:  If I impute a variables missing value using a CART regression tree, should I be concerned about my tree being too complex and overfitting that particular data?  When it comes time to use testing data, should I use that same tree model? Or should I build a new tree based off of my testing dataset?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you asking if we should be concerned if the model overfit in general, or if the estimate of the missing values "overfit"? From my point of view, the answer are yes for the first and no for the second

Comment: I am asking about the "model" built to predict the value of missing data points.  Your second question.

Comment: Can i ask you which model do you use the missing value imputation?

Comment: I was planning on using a regression tree to determine the value of missing values.

Comment: Are you doing single imputations?  Look into multiple imputation, and see if it isn't suitable for your task.

Answer (score -1):

You have overfitting when your model fit "too much" well the data. A model that fit the data well is attractive but we have always to keep in mind that almost all the models can be written as $y = f(x)+\epsilon$ where $x$ are

1) $x$ are covariates

2)$\epsilon$ the error term, generally assumed with independent components, unpredictable, outside our interested

3) $f()$ the part we are interested in.

and what we want to estimate is $f()$: $\hat{f}()$

If the model fit too well the data mean that it is able to reconstruct the data almost perfectly and this mean that you are modeling also the error term that are in fact unpredictible: $\hat{f}() \simeq f(x)+\epsilon$. Now if you try to use the model to predict some observations that are not used in the model estimate, since your estimate of $f$ is not correct you have value that are not correct. This is true also if you try to use $f()$ to estimate/imputate the missing value.